# Error con 000webhostapp al abrir el administrador de archivos

Tags: php, html, html5, phpmyadmin, hosting

Otra vez acudo a ustedes por que resulta que tengo subido mi sito en 000webhostapp y hoy que estoy intentando abrir el administrador de archivos me aparece el siguiente error:

```
{"result":{"success":false,"error":"URI must be a string or UriInterface","errorDetail":{"type":"InvalidArgumentException","code":0}}}
```

la cuenta que tengo es gratuita, pensé que era solamente con mi correo, probé con otros y me aparece lo mismo, intente con un celular y me aparece lo mismo, me conecte desde mi plan de datos y me sigue saliendo el error.

Probé con el motor de base de datos y ese sí funciona, me carga la base con toda la info.

Answer (score 1):

Les cuento que el problema continua, pero pude acceder a la direccion: https://files.000webhost.com/, usando filezila, configure el cliente ftp con los datos que nos dan al momento de crear el site y para mi sorpresa me pude conectar.

Les estare comentando por este medio si me entero de algo.

gracias a todos